# How to read the result by running did_multiplegt code in Stata

Tags: stata, difference-in-difference

One way of treating heterogeneous impact of staggered laws is to use did_multiplegt method developed by [Clément de Chaisemartin](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.08807).

When running the code suggested, I have the result as below, I do not understand how to read the result because there is no p-value or -t-value, so on and so forth

The code is

`did_multiplegt Y TYPE2 yr pt, robust_dynamic dynamic(5) placebo(5) breps(100) cluster(TYPE2) controls($independentvars)`

The result is

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've email Xavier D'Haultfoeuille about this.

This was his reply.

It works, I've used the code myself.

Stata code (after having run `did_multiplegt`):

```
ereturn list
scalar t_stat = e(effect_0)/e(se_effect_0)
scalar p_val = 2*normal(-abs(t_stat))

di t_stat, p_val
```

You can improve the code with loops.